# Block tags in turbogears/genshi (py:match)?

Tags: python, turbogears2, genshi

Ok, I'm coming from Django, so please excuse me if what I write doesn't make sense. I'm trying to "override" a portion of my master template in turbogears using genshi. So far I've only tried the py:match directive with no success:

master template:

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="menu-items" py:match="topmenu" py:attrs="select('@*')">
        ${select('*')}
    </div>
</div>
```

child template:

```
<topmenu> <span> HELLO! </span> </topmenu>
```

This renders `<span> HELLO! </span>` outside of the menu div. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Genshi py:match is a bit harsh to understand. The TurboGears2 documentation explains the concept quite well: *"given an XPath expression, it finds and replaces every element in the template that matches the expression – with the content of the element containing the py:match."*

This means that actually the element that has the py:match replaces the one that doesn't have it. So if you want to put the menu inside the master from the child template you should invert the two:

**MASTER:**

```
<body py:match="body" py:attrs="select('@*')">
    <topmenu id="menu-items"></topmenu>
</body>
```

**CHILD:**

```
<body>
    <div py:match="topmenu" py:attrs="select('@*')"><span>item1</span></div>
</body>
```

Using py:match is often more complex than what you need, I suggest you to take a look at the  header and footer implementation inside the quickstart template, they use an easier way to manage reusable template parts.

For the menu specific case you can also take a look at [tgext.menu](https://bitbucket.org/pedersen/tgext.menu/wiki/Home) it makes quite easy to handle menus and navbars inside turbogears applications.